# Observable over a non-array type

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services, reactive

I've created 3 Angular2 services that retrieve categories, locations and items from different http endpoints.  I'd now like to create a new service that retrieves data from those services and creates a new DataSet from all the data retrieved but I'm not able to create an Observable from the non-iterable DataSet object.

Is there a better way to consolidate data into a single structure like while using Observables?

```
export class DataSet {
  items: Item[];
  locations: Location[];
  categories: Category[];
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

_data : DataSet;

constructor(
    private _http: Http, 
    private _categoryService: CategoryService, 
    private _locationService: LocationService,
    private _itemService: ItemService) { }

getDataSet(): DataSet {
    this._data = new DataSet();

    this._categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(cats => {
        this._data.categories = cats;
    });

    this._locationService.getLocations().subscribe(locs => {
        this._data.locations = locs;
    });

    this._itemService.getItems(null).subscribe(items => {
        this._data.items = items;
    });

    // ERROR can't create observable from non array type dataset
    return Observable.from(this._data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `Observable.of` as in

```
return Observable.of(this._data);
```

You may need to add the import for the function explicitly using

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

**UPDATE:**

I was unhappy with my answer, as noted in comments it did not solve the underlying problem. So I have added a solution

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class DataService {

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private categoryService: { getCategories(): Observable<{ categoryName: string }[]> },
    private locationService: { getLocations(): Observable<{ locationName: string }[]> },
    private itemService: { getItems(options): Observable<{ itemName: string }[]> }) { }

  getDataSet() {
    return Observable
      .forkJoin(
        this.categoryService.getCategories(),
        this.locationService.getLocations(),
        this.itemService.getItems(undefined)
      )
      .map(([categories, locations, items]) => ({
        categories,
        locations,
        items
      }));
  }
}
```

`Observable.forkJoin` has the semantics you are looking for in that it preserves the distinction between the different input Observables by way of sequencing them into the resulting array of results.

Note this cleans up our code as well, as no longer have a mutable class field.

**Just some thoughts:**

Something I find interesting is that I had to use `Observable.forkJoin` (there may be a simpler way and please tell me if there is!) which is not a very discoverable function, and also happens to have no documentation in **ForkJoinObservable.d.ts**.

The reason this bothers me is that this question describes a fundamental scenario when using Observable as the interface for *singular* Web Requests. It should be obvious and intuitive, if we are to believe that Observable is the correct abstraction for this use case.

As soon as we talk about things like typeahead inputs that do asynchronous queries that return between 0 and some arbitrary n values over time, then yes, Observable imbued Web Requests would seem to become valuable.

The only problem with this is that, the typeahead scenario, which is sort of  the poster child for RxJS + Angular, involves *flatMapping* the results anyway. The whole abstraction is lifted to the level where RxJS is already applicable, relevant, and elegant, because the domain is that of streams.

Comment: Thanks Aluan, You answered the question regarding Observable.of but that didn't achieve the desired outcome.  I was expecting the the subscriber would not be called until the nested collections were populated but I think i need to look into observable chaining for that.

Comment: That is correct. You can use merge or fork join, or concat. All are different.

Comment: Of course there are a few dozen other ways to do the that in RxJS as well. Unfortunately the most obvious way, replacing all of the subscribe calls with map calls and then nesting then, will lead to unreadable code.

Comment: @Dennis Hey, I just updated my answer with a full solution.